# take screenshot in python as cronjob

Tags: python-3.x, screenshot

i need to take a screen shot ( both windows and linux ) but my code is started from cron / schedulle windows

this is my code:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # grab fullscreen
    im = ImageGrab.grab()

    # save image file
    im.save("screenshot.png")

    # show image in a window
    im.show()
```

this is returning me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/__init__.py", line 43, in grab
    return _grab(childprocess=childprocess, backend=backend, bbox=bbox)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/__init__.py", line 29, in _grab
    return childprocess_grab(_grab_simple, backend, bbox)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/childproc.py", line 34, in childprocess_grab
    return childprocess_grab_popen(backend, bbox)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/childproc.py", line 54, in childprocess_grab_popen
    raise FailedBackendError(p)
pyscreenshot.loader.FailedBackendError: <EasyProcess cmd_param=['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pyscreenshot.cli.grab_to_file', '/tmp/pyscreenshot0lficj00/screenshot.png', '0', '0', '0', '0', '--backend', ''] cmd=['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pyscreenshot.cli.grab_to_file', '/tmp/pyscreenshot0lficj00/screenshot.png', '0', '0', '0', '0', '--backend', ''] oserror=None return_code=1 stdout="" stderr="Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/cli/grab_to_file.py", line 8, in <module>
    def main(filename, x1, y1, x2, y2, backend=""):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/entrypoint2/__init__.py", line 440, in entrypoint
    return func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/cli/grab_to_file.py", line 28, in main
    im = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=bbox, childprocess=False, backend=backend)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/__init__.py", line 43, in grab
    return _grab(childprocess=childprocess, backend=backend, bbox=bbox)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/__init__.py", line 31, in _grab
    return _grab_simple(backend, bbox, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/__init__.py", line 17, in _grab_simple
    return backend_obj.grab(bbox)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/plugins/scrot.py", line 24, in grab
    im = read_prog_img([PROGRAM, "--silent"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/tempexport.py", line 28, in read_prog_img
    im = read_func_img(run_prog)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/tempexport.py", line 16, in read_func_img
    func(filename, bbox)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyscreenshot/tempexport.py", line 26, in run_prog
    raise RunProgError(p.stderr)
pyscreenshot.tempexport.RunProgError: giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?" timeout_happened=False>
```

i need help to solve it please.
i tried to change lib but none that i found yet worked.

---

i noticed that if i run in crontab or ssh with a user my code runs but in root dont.
( i need to execute it with sudo to make some systems adjustments , file moves and read logs )

Comment: Did you look at the error?  Whatever library you're using needs to be run under an X environment.

Comment: yes in running it under a X eviroment my raspbaerry is using a desktop raspíbian. wy it cant to be runned from crontab?

Comment: Most of the time, cron jobs aren't run in an X environment.  I'm not sure you can even run one from an X environment, but you maybe able to set environment variables to fake it.

Comment: do you know how to do it ?

Comment: i found one more thing. if i run my code with sudo python3 code.py this returns this error but with python3 code.py it works. only in sudo this happenings

Answer (score 0):

To take a screenshot is actually pretty simple.
First install pyautogui.

```
pip install pyautogui
```

then the code:

```
import pyautogui
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save("path/to/file.png")
```